# Currently failing to create a class which recursively forms a tree of instances from a hash

Tags: ruby

This is a problem from a textbook: to take a previously demonstrated tree-generating program and make it generate a tree of instances with names determined by a hash. Code below. There are a number of things I don't understand. First, what is the purpose of the first line? I see that it "defines an instance variable, an accessor, and a setter," but what does that mean? Second, why are we passing around a block for 'puts node.node_name' rather than just putting that in the 'visit' method? Third, that line is the only time that 'node' is referred to in this entire program. It doesn't appear to be defined. So what is it? And finally, what am I doing wrong here? How can I make this work?

-Thanks.

```
class Day4thing3
  attr_accessor :children, :node_name

  def initialize (name, children = {})
    @children = children
    @node_name = name
    children.each do
      |a,b| 
      a = Day4thing3.new(a, b)
    end
  end

  def visit_all (&block)
    visit &block
    children.each_key {|c| c.visit_all &block}
  end

  def visit(&block)
    block.call self
  end

children = {'grandpa'=>{'dad'=>{'child1'=>{},'child2'=>{}},'uncle'=>{'cousin1'=>{},'cousin2'=>{}}}}
family = Day4thing3.new("family", children)

  family.visit_all {|node| puts node.node_name}
end
```

**output:**

family
C:/Users/Aidan/Documents/Apps and App Files/Eclipse/eclipse/workspace/Day 4/day4thing3.rb:16:in `block in visit_all': undefined method`visit_all' for "grandpa":String (NoMethodError)
    from C:/Users/Aidan/Documents/Apps and App Files/Eclipse/eclipse/workspace/Day 4/day4thing3.rb:16:in `each_key'
    from C:/Users/Aidan/Documents/Apps and App Files/Eclipse/eclipse/workspace/Day 4/day4thing3.rb:16:in`visit_all'
    from C:/Users/Aidan/Documents/Apps and App Files/Eclipse/eclipse/workspace/Day 4/day4thing3.rb:36:in `<class:Day4thing3>'
    from C:/Users/Aidan/Documents/Apps and App Files/Eclipse/eclipse/workspace/Day 4/day4thing3.rb:1:in`'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> First, what is the purpose of the first line? I see that it "defines an instance variable, an accessor, and a setter," but what does that mean?

```
attr_accessor :children
```

is a shortcut, equivalent to

```
def children
  @children
end
def children=(value)
  @children = value
end
```

`@children` is an instance variable, i.e. a variable that each instance of a class can set individually (John has his children, Jane has her children...). A getter is a method that gets the value of an instance variable. A setter is a method that sets it. After this, you can write

```
p node.children          # uses the getter
node.children = []       # uses the setter
```

> Second, why are we passing around a block for 'puts node.node_name' rather than just putting that in the 'visit' method?

Because that makes `visit` generic. You can visit all nodes and print them, you can visit all nodes and sum them, etc etc. If you hardcode a single purpose into `visit`, then you would need to code a new function every time you think of a new thing you would like to do to all nodes.

> Third, that line is the only time that 'node' is referred to in this entire program. It doesn't appear to be defined. So what is it?

A block is like a function: it has input parameters and a return value. `node` happens to be the input parameter of the block `{ |node| puts node.node_name }`. So, its value will be whatever the `yield` or `call` passes to the block; in this case, the block is invoked by `block.call self`, so `node` inside the block is the value of `self` inside the `#visit` method.

> And finally, what am I doing wrong here?

Before that... let's talk about naming. `Day4thing3` is a horrible class name. By all means, save it in a file called `day4thing3.rb` if you want; if you want to namespace it, put it into a module named `Day4Thing3`; but please name the class `Node`, or `Tree`, or something meaningful. Because this makes no sense:

A `Day4thing3` assumes its children are also a `Day4thing3`.

but this does:

A `Node` assumes its children are also a `Node`.

Anyway - you try to change the hash keys into `Node` objects, but `a` is just a parameter - assigning to it will not change the key in the hash. You could use `Hash#transform_keys` for that. However, you are not using `values` at all after the constructor, so changing `@children` into an `Array` would make more sense.

So when you `visit_all`, you `visit` the current node, then `visit_all` the child nodes. This works on your `"family"` `Node`: you print the node name (`"family"`) and then try to visit all the children keys. However, the key is `"grandpa"`, which is a `String` and not a `Node` (remember, `a = Node.new(a, b)` did not change the hash, only the local variable `a`), so the function fails.

A final point, regarding style: method names should not be separated from the parentheses by a space. It works for definition, it breaks for invocation; using "no space" rule makes it consistent.

So, with all that:

```
module Day4Thing3
  class Node
    attr_accessor :children, :node_name

    def initialize(name, children={})
      @node_name = name
      @children = children.map do |child_name, child_children|
        Node.new(child_name, child_children)
      end
    end

    def visit_all(&block)
      visit &block
      children.each { |child| child.visit_all &block }
    end

    def visit(&block)
      block.call self
    end
  end

  children = {'grandpa'=>{'dad'=>{'child1'=>{},'child2'=>{}},'uncle'=>{'cousin1'=>{},'cousin2'=>{}}}}
  family = Node.new("family", children)

  family.visit_all {|node| puts node.node_name}
end
```

Comment: I wonder what would be wrong with `yield self` everywhere instead of `visit(&block)` :)

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin I know you don't need to ask this :) but... a tiny bit faster, and a tad less readable, in general case - no other difference.

Comment: Not only. When the block is [mistakenly] omitted, `visit(&block)` raises cryptic _NoMethodError: undefined method 'call' for nil:NilClass_ while `yield` reports the real cause _LocalJumpError: no block given (yield)_.

Comment: Thank you for the very thorough answer.